# Pass selected value server side dropdown list to javascript function

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I have web form and JavaScript function like this:

**web form**

```
<div>
    <asp:DropDownList runat="server" ID="ddlType">
        <asp:ListItem Value="1" Text="Type1"></asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem Value="2" Text="Type2"></asp:ListItem>
    </asp:DropDownList>
    <asp:LinkButton  ID="lnkTest" OnClientClick='<%= "getValue('0' + '|' + 'ddlType.SelectedValue');return false;" %>' runat="server" Text="text">
                           new
    </asp:LinkButton>
</div>
```

**JavaScript function**

```
<script>
    function getValue(Input) {       
        var result = Input.split("|");
        section1 = result[0];
        section2 = result[1];
    }
</script>
```

I need to pass string includes `'0'` (hardcoded) and `ddlType.SelectedValue` to `getValue`.
This web form has syntax error `Server tags cannot contain <% ... %> constructs` (I know). I can get selected value by `getElementById` but I want to pass `SelectedValue` as argument. I read many posts but none of them don't pass `SelectedValue`.

It would be very helpful if someone could explain solution for this problem.

Answer (score 0):

SelectedValue is a server-side value. It's available to the server-side code at page load (i.e. before the page is rendered to the user). In javascript it has no meaning at all, and isn't available at the time when a user clicks on the link.

If you want to get the selected value on the client side you can do something like this:

First get rid of the all the OnClientClick code from your LinkButton.

Second, write some javascript like this (at the bottom of the page, after all your HTML/ASP markup:

```
document.getElementById("<%=lnkTest.ClientID %>").addEventListener("click", function(event) {
  event.preventDefault(); //stop default action of the link button, to allow script to execute
  var selectedVal = document.getElementById("<%=ddlType.ClientID %>").value;
  getValue('0|' + selectedVal);
});
```

This will cause the browser to listen for a user clicking on the button, and then run the JS function given. That function fetches the currently selected value of the dropdown (as selected in the browser - at this point the server has no idea what's selected because no postback has happened) and passes that selected value to your existing `getValue` function.

N.B. In case you're wondering, the reason I use the contruct `<%=ddlType.ClientID %>` is because ASP.NET dynamically creates the client-side ID of each element based on the structure of the server-side controls it lies within. So just relying directly on the server-side ID (e.g. "ddlType") will not reliably identify the element in the rendered DOM. .NET provides the ClientID value at runtime in order to allow us to access the generated ID.

Comment: Thanks for answer.‍I think `document.getElementById("<%=lnkTest.ClientID %>").addEventListener("click", function(event)` in your code is equivalent to `OnClientClick`.But I need pass `value` of `ddlType` in `OnClientClick` event as argument.Then I tested `ddlType.ClientID` in `OnClientClick` but isn't work properly.

Comment: No, you don't need to do that, mainly because you _can't_, as I've already explained. My version is the equivalent using the correct client-side code, and produces your desired outcome.

Comment: Are you sure that I can't pass `selectedValue` as argument?

Comment: yes because it almost certainly won't let you put the <% %> in, which you need in order to identify ddlType on the client properly. There's no need to get hung up on using the OnClientClick syntax - my version is an exact equivalent of that. And you'll notice within my version, it then passed selectedValue to your `getValue` function _as an argument_, just the same. Lastly, from a design point of view most developers now agree that using the event listener syntax (as I have done) is much better than doing inline script calls (because it promotes re-use and code/presentation separation)

Comment: `OnClientClick` is **string** in System.Web.dll (see [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.button.onclientclick(v=vs.110).aspx)). I tried to set this string by javascript but I could't. I think there is a way for convert selectedvalue to string by using script tag in html attribute (like [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3452485/can-a-javascript-variable-be-used-in-plain-html))and pass to function.

Comment: Why are you still worrying about onclientclick???? You **don't need it**. Just use addEventListener instead (as per my example). It's the **exact equivalent functionality**, and completely avoids the problems you are having with setting the string. Have you even tried my example?