# Pass JavaScript JSON variable from index.js into index.html

Tags: javascript, html

This is my index.js file:

```
 function fun()
{
 var obj;
}
```

This is my index.html file:

```
<script>
  src="js/index.js"
</script>
```

I want to use variable `obj` here.

I saw some solutions to create a variable and pass in index.html but is there any way of injection?

Actually, `obj` is a JSON object. I forgot to mention that previously. How would I use the JSON object keys and values in my index.html outside of the script tag?

Comment: `obj` is local to the `fun()` function. Where are you trying to use it?

Comment: A variable cannot be used outside of script tags in HTML.  Also, your [script](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/script) needs to have the source `attribute` inside the tag.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can a JavaScript variable be used in plain HTML?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3452485/can-a-javascript-variable-be-used-in-plain-html)

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan i think for my question its not totally apt

Comment: What do you mean by JSON object? Is it string?

Comment: You need to [edit] your question to include information as to how this question differs from the proposed duplicate. Both of them ask the question of how to show a JavaScript variable in HTML.

Answer (score 0):

Although there isn't any way to inject a JS variable into HTML simply, you can use a javascript function to do the same thing:

In index.js:

```
function fun()
{
    return obj; // Assuming obj is a defined variable.
}
document.getElementById("toReplace").innerHTML = fun();
```

In index.html

```
<p id="toReplace"></p>
<script src="index.js"></script>
```

Essentially, your javascript will replace the content of the <p> tag, which has the ID "toReplace", with the value of fun().

Comment: Make sure the DOM is ready, or call the script below the p-tag.

Answer (score 0):

Try out [AngularJS](http://angularjs.org). With this, you can declare variables in `$scope` and use it in your html like:

JavaScript:

```
...some angular logic...
$scope.foo = "bar";
...some other angular logic...
```

HTML:

```
<p>{{foo}}</p>
```

There are many tutorials out there. Read the documentation. It may be what you are looking for.