# Calling Random Value using javascript

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I'm trying to randomize value using `javascript` but after trying for several hours I am failed continuously many time.

Here is the code which I am using.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var banner1 = ["ca-pub-3060228829854466", "8550285936"];
var banner2 = ["ca-pub-3680851546903667", "4280702589"];
var allbanner = [banner1, banner2];
var banner = allbanner[Math.floor(Math.random() * allbanner.length)];
</script>
```

I have added two array `banner[0]` and `banner[1]`. when I am using in another `JS`, it not calling the value's.

```
<script async src="//pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/js/adsbygoogle.js"></script>
<!-- 336*280 -->
<ins class="adsbygoogle"
     style="display:inline-block;width:336px;height:280px"
     data-ad-client="banner[0]"
     data-ad-slot="banner[1]"></ins>
<script>
(adsbygoogle = window.adsbygoogle || []).push({});
</script>
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Hi Ivan86, I already tried without apostrophes but it breaking the code. It is inside <ins></ins> tag. Thanks for your reply

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php
function generateRandomString($length = 10) {
$characters = '0123456789';
$randomString = '';
for ($i = 0; $i < $length; $i++) {
    $randomString .= $characters[rand(0, strlen($characters) - 2)];
}
return $randomString;
}
?>

 <script type="text/javascript">
 var banner1 = ["ca-pub-3060228829854466", "<?php echo generateRandomString();?>"];
 var banner2 = ["ca-pub-3680851546903667", "<?php echo generateRandomString();?>"];
 var allbanner = [banner1, banner2];
 var banner = allbanner[Math.floor(Math.random() * allbanner.length)];
 </script>
```

Comment: Hi zabkas. Thanks for replying. You didn't understand my questions. it not about generating random value. It about calling random value to one JS to another JS from array. 

and only in JS not in PHP.

Comment: if you want have random specific digits that you for example have saved somewhere else then that's another way. Let me know :D

Comment: I'm trying to call values randomly from my javascript (array) to another javascript. The value is already defined in array. i just want to call in my another js. I ignore PHP because it do not support in .html

Comment: I understod ! why are u asking something that is nothing with php to do and tagging php ?

Comment: Please check my screenshot : http://prntscr.com/i6spl1 . Hope you understand what i really need. I need in JS because the file i'm using it .html extension which do not support PHP Tag.

Answer (score 1):

If they are actually in different script tags, you can't share a `var` across scopes like that. You can assign it globally to the window variable by leaving out the `var` but that's not ideal.

so you would need to change

```
var banner = allbanner[Math.floor(Math.random() * allbanner.length)];
```

to

```
banner = allbanner[Math.floor(Math.random() * allbanner.length)];
```

Edit: You cannot access javascript variables outside of a script tag in plain old vanilla javascript. [Can a JavaScript variable be used in plain HTML?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3452485/can-a-javascript-variable-be-used-in-plain-html)

Comment: Hi Ballmerspeak. I have tried your code. It not working fine. Please check my screenshot. Hope it help you to understand what i really need : http://prntscr.com/i6spl1

Comment: See my edit but you can't use javascript variables outside of script tags with just vanilla JS

Comment: As you mentioned the Javascript cannot be called or used outside tag then how this script only working fine `<script>
document.write(banner[0]);

document.write(banner[1]);

</script>`

Comment: That code is in a script tag. The <ins> is not in a script tag

Answer (score 1):

You can to give your `<ins>` an `id` so you can target it from javascript using `document.getElementById()` and then using `element.setAttribute()` to set its data attributes.

> **`element.setAttribute()`** sets the value of an attribute on the specified element. If the attribute already exists, the value is updated; otherwise a new attribute is added with the specified name and value.

reference:[developer.mozilla.org/setAttribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/setAttribute).

**Here is the corrected code:**

```html
<script async src="//pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/js/adsbygoogle.js"></script>
<!-- 336*280 -->
<ins id="insId"
     class="adsbygoogle"
     style="display:inline-block;width:336px;height:280px"
     data-ad-client=""
     data-ad-slot=""></ins>

<script type="text/javascript">
  var banner1 = ["ca-pub-3060228829854466", "8550285936"];
  var banner2 = ["ca-pub-3680851546903667", "4280702589"];
  var allbanner = [banner1, banner2];
  var banner = allbanner[Math.floor(Math.random() * allbanner.length)];

  var el = document.getElementById("insId");

  el.setAttribute('data-ad-client', banner[0]);
  el.setAttribute('data-ad-slot', banner[1]);

  // the below two lines are only for the purpose of the snippet
  console.log('data-ad-client: ' + el.getAttribute('data-ad-client'));
  console.log('data-ad-slot: ' + el.getAttribute('data-ad-slot'));
</script>

<script>
(adsbygoogle = window.adsbygoogle || []).push({});
</script>
```